# Better way to access a subtask in custom grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, gruntjs, task

I'm new to Grunt and I've only built a few custom grunt tasks. My solution for traversing the initConfig to subtasks seems pretty unintuitive--I just threw a regex together and used a switch to figure out which subtask should be running. Is there a better way of getting here? Here's a sample Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        myTask: {
            add:{
               //files object, options etc
            },
            remove:{
               //files object, options etc                
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerMultiTask('myTask', 'A sample task with a regex and switch for subtasks', function() {
        var subTask = this.nameArgs.match(/.*?:(.*?):/)[1];
        switch(subTask){
            case "add":
                //code for task "add"
                break;
            case "remove":
                //code for task "remove"
                break;
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've looked into this before, and I never found a good solution other than just splitting on the colon `:`

Comment: @jakerella even that's a step in the right direction. Thanks! I hadn't even thought of split for some reason. Still though, it seems like there should be something in the API to avoid the need.

Answer (score 0):

In a multitask, the "subtask" is known as a target. It's accessible via `this.target`. For example (taken from  http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  log: {
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: 'hello world',
    baz: false
  }
});

grunt.task.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
});
```

Running `grunt log:foo` would write out `foo: 1,2,3`.

So in your code, you could replace the Regex line with:

```
var subTask = this.target;
```